# Site specific ISAPI filter

Tags: iis, isapi

I'm currently using appcmd to configure IIS. I need to set an ISAPI filter at the site level, rather than globally - something achievable via the UI.
However I cannot see any way to specify the site following the examples in the IIS pages :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754174(v=ws.10).aspx

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
appcmd.exe set config "{SiteName}" -section:system.webServer/isapiFilters /+"[@{Position},name='{Name}',path='{FilterPath}',enabled='{Enabled}',enableCache='{EnableCache}',preCondition='{PreCondition}']" /commit:apphost
```